# Would someone help me improve my posts?

Tags: support, post-ban

I was recently banned from asking questions. This was due, in part, to writing a post requesting textbooks. I hadn't read the rules, which outlaw that kind of thing.

I see that the general prescription for regaining question-asking abilities is to edit your old posts. However, when I look through these old posts, I don't really see how I could edit them. In some cases, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60438833/coding-case-10-of-marching-squares-2-isolines), they just seem so obscure that editing wouldn't help. I actually solved that problem myself, so I could perhaps post the solution to it in an edit. The other posts seem okay to me, but I'm new. Could someone offer me advice?

To reiterate, it seems to me that my posts are mostly just obscure so they go unvoted. And on occasion I have lazily made posts. Am I off-base? Are there specific posts of mine that might be better to edit than others?

Comment: re: the question that you found the solution to, if you're going to post an answer, *Post an Answer*. Don't edit it into the question. Make sure the question is in good shape, helpful to others, and that the answer is, too.

Comment: Thanks Paul. It does not fully answer my question, as I was interested in feedback specific to my posts. In my case, I feel like my posts were not received well because not many people work with things like marching squares. However, I will go back and edit my posts. Perhaps they were too unclear or too long. And I can contribute through comments. It's just that my knowledge level is low so I don't often have much to contribute.

Comment: *Do* read that linked post -- it's an extensive FAQ about this topic.

Comment: Yes, good question. There are three. One pertaining to the book question. One very poorly written, which I will edit. And one which I think wasn't right for the forum, but with 0 upvotes. I have undeleted the two.

Comment: You can also post links to the questions here. Users with >10k can see them if they have the link.

Comment: There must be more 3 bad questions isn’t typically enough to result in a question ban.

Comment: I promise that's all there is. Perhaps I could have been more polite to the user who closed my textbook question. I wasn't exactly impolite though, so I don't know. Just three posts.

Comment: The user only has [1 deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61164071), which I just deleted today because it is completely unsalvageable. All their other questions are [publicly visible](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12919727/reformed-hen?tab=questions). Note that the quality ban doesn't *just* take into account downvoted posts. If a user has asked a large number of questions, and most are zero-scored with some downvoted questions, they're going to end up question-banned. That's what happened in this case. I suspect many of the zero-score questions can be improved by edits.